# Add a banner image after first post, across the WordPress website

Tags: loop, query, pre-get-posts

I am looking for a way to add a banner image after first post across the website.

If it was about adding a banner on one page only, homepage or category page, then I could have done this in WordPress loop.

```
if ( $wp_query->current_post == 0 ) {
   echo '<p align="center"><a href="http://www.domain.com/"><img src="http://www.domain.com/banner.jpg" alt="Banner" /></a></p>';
}
```

And this works but can't we do something with `pre_get_posts` or use some other function to achieve this across the website. On homepage, authors, archive, categories, search and tags pages.

Comment: if you have a `loop-posts.php` file and call it via `get_template_part()` I don't see why it would not work?

Comment: There is always the `the_post` filter :-)

Comment: I also don't think injecting a banner via `pre_get_posts` or `the_posts` filter will work if your banner is not a complete post object

Comment: @Sisir That works but `content.php` is used in almost all loops across the pages, including many custom `WP_Query`. Custom loops do not need banner.

Comment: I just remebered a very similar question which was answered by @birgire. This can be base to your solution :-)

Comment: PieterGoosen, Solution posted by @birgire works just great. Thanks both of you. :)

Comment: Glad you found it useful. You could also take the `$q->current_post` as an input parameter in `do_action`, to make it more flexible. @PieterGoosen Thanks for remembering it ;-)

Comment: @birgire that was the first post that came to mind, just had to search for it first, lol ;-)

Comment: @birgire Thanks for the tip. You guys are awesome. :-)